# Como passar Id junto de paginação ex: index?pag=pagina&ID?

Tags: php, mysql

Estou fazendo um site e neste site, tenho um sitema de paginação simples na index.php com o seguinte codigo:

```
<?php
    function getGet( $key ){
            return isset( $_GET[ $key ] ) ? $_GET[ $key ] : null;
    }
            $pg = getGet('pag');
            if( is_file( 'Paginas/'.$pg.'.php' ) )
                    include 'Paginas/'.$pg.'.php'; 
            else
                    include 'Paginas/home.php';
```

Tenho uma pagina chamada *estudos* que fica nesta paginação acima e dentro dela(pagina estudos), tenho um sistema de paginação que passa mais parametros `$_Get`, como Id, para gerar a paginação por Contagem igual a esta:

[image: usando o get ela passa um id <code>?pag=1<b</code>]

Alguem sabe o modo de passar `INDEX?PAG=ESTUDOS` e dentro de estudo o id da paginação? Acho que seja algo mais ou menos assim `index?pag=estudos&1` só que não sei como fazer.

Comment: Geralmente uma paginação é alimentada pelo conteúdo do DB - o que você está fazendo é manual `is_file( 'Paginas/'.$pg.'.php' )`, você tem os arquivos `pg1.php, pg2.php, ... pg100.php` de forma fisica?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Todas as variáveis passadas na URL após o sinal de `?` (separadas por `&`) podem ser obtidas no PHP usando o array [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) como no diagrama abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
$_GET['pag'] == 'estudos'
$_GET['pagina'] == 1
$_GET['tipo'] == 'avançado'
```

Ou seja, a sua linha:

```
$pg = getGet('pag');
```

é quase o mesmo que:

```
$pg = $_GET['pag'];
```

Comment: Pessoal, votem mais nesta resposta!

Answer (score 4):

Os parâmetros passados por GET precisam estar no formato `chave=valor`. Portanto, você pode fazer algo assim:

```
index.php?secao=estudos&pagina=1
```

(Ajuste os nomes dos parâmetros conforme a sua necessidade.)

Comment: Você quer dizer passar uma Session_start ?
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-start.php

Comment: Session_start? Estou mostrando como passar mais de um parâmetro por GET: "estudos" e o número da página. Talvez não tenha entendido direito a pergunta.

Comment: o que é bfavaretto indicou, é um `link` que vai passar o n. da página e você só precisa usar `$_GET['pagina']` para recupera-la.

Comment: Vlw Amigo agora deu certo !!! Não tinha dado certo porque eu tinha colocado um mesmo $_GET para seção e pagina vlw

Comment: Não esqueça de marcar como resolvido

Comment: Ao escolher o que marcar como resolvido, considere a resposta do Jader, que é mais detalhada.

Answer (score 1):

é como o Jader falou acima, chave=valor:

`index.php?secao=estudos&pagina=1`

E no seu controller (ou algo parecido) pra saber qual página você deve mandar você faz o seguinte:

```
/*
aqui resgatamos o valor, caso ele não exista ou não seja um inteiro o valor
atribuido a $pagina ser 0 (zero) 
*/
$pagina = (int) $_GET['pagina'];

/*
se o valor for 0 mudamos para um porque imagino que você não tenha a página 0
*/
$pagina = ($pagina == 0) ? 1 : $pagina;
```

Agora o mesmo com secao

```
$secao = $_GET['secao'];
$secao = ($secao == '') ? 'sua_secao_default' : $secao;
```